# Kendo spreadsheet browser compatibility

Tags: kendo-ui, kendospreadsheet

Does kendo spreadsheet supported in IE9? cause when I import excel into it, it's not working. If it is not supported in IE9, is there any workaround that I can do to load the excel in the spreadsheet?

Answer (score -1):

The spreadsheet requires IE9 or latest as announced in Telerik website. 
"The Spreadsheet supports Internet Explorer 9 and later versions. The widget is primarily targeted at desktop users and, therefore, its performance and functionalities on mobile devices are limited."

https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/controls/data-management/spreadsheet/overview

By my knowledge you may experience some issues regarding the styling in IE9. Better if you have the change to target above IE9